# Is this statement about thermodynamic entropy true?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, entropy

Is the following statement true?

The entropy of a placid lake is greater than that of the streams that feed it but less than that of the effluent from its dam’s turbines.

If not, in what way is it incorrect?

Comment: The entropy of a cubic meter of water is 1000 times as large as that of one liter of the same temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to apply the second Principle of thermodynamics. However, a river and a lake are not **isolated sistems**, so you cannot apply it and your question is not meaningful.